# google protobuf3 how to convert Messages to Json?

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

Anyone can share some idea how to convert Messages to Json in google protobuf3?
since in protobuf2 there is a method call json_formate.MessagesToJson can easily to convert message to json, however in the version 3 this method disappeared... anyone could share some ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That method is still there: [`google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToJson`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#L99) ([docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/)).